# providing a 'save-as' option to user for downloading a file using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, user-agent

I have provided an API to the user to download a file by passing the filename as a URL parameter:

```
https://example.com/download_file/<filename>
```

in my python code, I'll use the filename to create the header URL and make a request to another server:

```
import requests
url = 'http://<route>/{}'.format(filename)
headers = {'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename="myfile.txt"','User-Agent' : 'baby_yoda','Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
return r
```

This does not provide the 'save as' option to the user on the browser. I know I'm missing something, but not sure what I should be looking for. printing 'r' shows a '200 status' only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
from flask import Response
import requests
url = 'http://<route>/{}'.format(filename)
headers = {'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename="myfile.txt"','User-Agent' : 'baby_yoda','Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'}
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
return Response(stream_with_context(r.iter_content(chunk_size=2048)), headers = headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
return r.text
```

`requests.get` returns an object that contains a lot of information in different attributes. Therefore, to access the body of the resulting file you need to add: `.text`.

Comment: I needed to let the user download the file as an attachment. accessing the test wouldnt help in this case.